# c# publish of net winform missing sqlite.interop.dll

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, c#-3.0

Published from Visual Studio 2022 community.  I have been working on this form now for a while and have been publishing it to my desktop as I complete specific tasks.  Now, for whatever reason when I publish this, I receive the missing sqlite.interop.dll

[image]
If you notice, it did load one of the sqlite packages, but not the core or any of the others that were installed with NutGet.
Also, I started looking in my project folders and found this dll in both the x86 and x84 folder
[image]
[image]

I have seen a number of questions here on this with different solutions (modify the csproj file).  But that did not work for me.  I would back up the project and create a new one, copying all the resource, class, and design files in.  But I am not sure that would resolve the problem and I could make the matters worse.

Suggestions please?